# Calculate average per user

Tags: mysql

I need to figure out the certification percentage using mysql queries, and is wondering if someone could give me pointers. Below are some sample sets:

```
User 1: Failed: 1; Passed: 1 == Certified: Yes
User 2: Failed: 0; Passed: 1 == Certified: Yes
User 3: Failed: 3; Passed: 0 == Certified: No
User 4: Failed: 2; Passed: 1 == Certified: Yes
User 5: Failed: 4; Passed: 0 == Certified: No
```

Certification Percentage = 60%

This is how the data could look like in the DB:

```
CourseName  StudentName StudentEmail    Status  
Course A    BB Tester   b@b.com         Pass
Course B    BB Tester   b@b.com         Fail
Course B    AA Tester   a@a.com         Fail
Course B    AA Tester   a@a.com         Fail
Course B    AA Tester   a@a.com         Pass
Course C    CC Tester   c@c.com         Pass
Course D    DD Tester   d@d.com         Fail
```

How should I comprise the queries. It has to be done at a user level, so I suspect subqueries?

Comment: yuo want calculate amount of students having status  pass at least one time to  all students?

Comment: Can you clarify the criteria which determine Certified or not?  Is it any one `Pass` for certification? Do you want percentage certified per course?  Given the input sample table you provided, please also provide the exact output results you're expecting.

Comment: Man this question needs some help, plus it's a do it all for me, no schema.

Comment: `select pass.pass/total.total*100 from (select count(distinct StudentName) pass from tablename where Status="Pass") pass, (select count(distinct StudentName) total from tablename) total`

Comment: @DrewPierce But it doesn't meet any of the criteria for closing?

Comment: @Strawberry yes. Was hoping he'd come back and support his own question

Comment: Thank you so much for responses. I want to calculate total percentage of certified users. This would calculate all certified users over non-certified users regardless of how many times it took someone to pass the exam.

Comment: I want to calculate total percentage of certified users. This would calculate all certified users over non-certified users regardless of how many times it took someone to pass the exam. I hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
SELECT ((SELECT count(*) FROM `your_data` WHERE `status`='Pass') / count(*))*100 FROM your_data
```

Or this formatted version:

```
SELECT CONCAT(ROUND((SELECT count(*) FROM `your_data` WHERE `status`='Pass') / count(*))*100,2),'%') FROM `your_data`
```

Comment: I just ran the query. Thank you so much. I really appreciate. It seemed to give the results that I was expecting.